# Best practice for which Response Code to use for invalid requests?

Tags: apache-2.2, http

There are a few sites that are linking back to mine, but they are invalid URLs; content that I've never had on my site. I know that for content I have moved I should be using 301 and content that I have deleted I should be using a 410. But for something like this, I don't foresee those sites coming back and correcting their links, one of which is in the footer of a persons signature on a forum in China. Do I just send the 410 and let it be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct response code to use for such requests is 404, and that is also what Apache will send by default.